# Fix a broken floor pump, replace pump head

Tags: pump

The little plastic lever to tighten the o-ring broke on my floor pump. It's probably fifteen years old. The model is a Pyramid Pro. The broken bit is highlighted in red.

[image]

There's nothing else wrong with it and it seems silly to toss the whole thing over so small a problem. Is it supposed to be easy to replace the head on cheapo pumps like this? I cannot easily figure out how any of the pieces are supposed to come apart. Neither end of the hose screws apart. There's a large allen key hole that I think allows for dismantling the whole lower plastic housing, but it's not obvious to me that the hose is in any sense replaceable.

I assume the answer is I'm just being stupid cheap and need to a buy a new pump. Just checking first.

Comment: Nevermind, the head does come unscrewed. I had to use pliers to get enough leverage. I see plenty of replacement heads.

Comment: I had virtually the identical failure on my pump about 18 months back.  I found an exact replacement hose assembly on the web, and the price was not terribly high.  Google finds (on Amazon) a replacement for the Pyramid Pro hose assembly quite easily, and the price looks good.  (Besides, the hose assemblies are likely interchangeable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slica makes a very nice [presta pump head](http://silca.cc/collections/all-silca/products/silca-17-4-stainless-presta-head) (below), the cost in the US is around $35. For that it ought to work well – and it does. The connection is a Schrader (car tire) thread and it is a pain to find a hose barb with that thread. What I did was to cut off the end of the hose and then use the threads on the pump head as a hose barb. I put a hose clamp on it and it holds just fine.

[image]

Comment: That does look nice but a new really nice SKS pump is $55, so $36 for just the head seems like a lot.

Comment: And that is a prime symptom of our throw-away society.  People don't by the part cos its expensive, so fewer are made/stocked which makes them expensive.

Comment: Well I found generic replacement heads for ~$8 on Amazon, so I was commenting more specifically on the price of this one metal piece.